# C++ dependency injection (if client has to perform some work that needs to be passed to the ctor of the injected object)

Tags: c++, dependency-injection

all this ctor-injection and setter-injection examples assume that the object to be injected can be constructed without any previous work that had to be performed e.g. in the ctor of the client object.

But how can I avoid tight coupling and at the same time pass the injected objects some arguments that were only calculated in the ctor of the class that is going to be receive the injected object?

```
struct Interface{
  virtual void process() = 0;
};

struct Concrete : Interface{
  Concrete(int i) : m_i{i}{}
  void process() override {};
  int m_i;
};

struct Client{
  Client(){
    int i = someCalculation();
    ptr = std::make_shared<Concrete>(i);
  }
  std::shared_ptr<Interface> ptr;
};
```

So I cannot construct the Concrete instance before and then pass it to the client as it depends on clients data.

What is the solution here that break this tight coupling?

Answer (score 1):

Two general tips: Don't take design patterns too literally. Don't apply them for their own sake, blindy as written in the book. Secondly, a level of indirection. There is almost no problem that cannot be solved by adding a level of indirection.

In your specific case, simply pass another object that creates the injected object:

```
struct Interface{
    virtual void process() = 0;
    virtual ~Interface() {}
};

struct Concrete : Interface {
    Concrete(int) {}
    void process() override {};
};

struct InterfaceFactory {
    std::shared_ptr<Interface> create(int i) const { 
        return std::make_shared<Concrete>(i);
    }
};

int someCalculation() { return 42; }

struct Client{
    Client(const InterfaceFactory& f) :  ptr(f.create(someCalculation())) {}
    std::shared_ptr<Interface> ptr;
};
```

In other words: Use a factory when code creating the object should be agnostic of details of the construction.

Comment: thank you, but I dont get how this solves above problem. In your code example, the creation happens in the ctor-initializer list and uses the in-class initializer for i. But what if there is some work to be done in the ctor of the client the results of which are to be used to initialize the concrete instance?

Comment: @CD86 typically you do not want to initialize members in the constructor. Members are initialized before the body of the constructor is executed. If you need to call a function to retrieve the value of `i` then just call the function, and then pass `i` to the factory

Comment: @CD86 it solves "the problem" because `Client` needs to know nothing about `Concrete` (only that it implements `Interace` and that it can be created via `InterfaceFactory`). If necessary it could also get only a reference to an abstract class for the factory, but its not necessary here.

Comment: @CD86 oh sorry, I misread your code. I thought `i` is a member. I think now I have the code to match yours

Comment: @CD86 actually now I am not sure where to call to `someCalcuation` is supposed to happen. If not in `Client` you can move it to the factory